# Determine if SaveAs FileFormat is PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I want to make changes to an Excel worksheet before it is saved to PDF and undo those changes after the copy has been created. I thought of using the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event to implement the changes and the `Workbook_AfterSave` event to return the worksheet to its original state.

The point at which I got stuck is when I want to determine the output format for the SaveAs instruction. It doesn't seem to be available in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event, and I know of no event that I might capture the SaveAs dialog with unless I force the user to use a particular instance of this dialog.

I would like the user to choose SaveAs from Excel's UI and take action if he chose to save as PDF.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the file path and extension by controlling the `msoFileDialogSaveAs` like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String

    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show

    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        strPath = _
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
        'displays the result in a message box
        Call MsgBox(strPath, vbInformation, "Save Path")
    End If

    SaveAsUI = False
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

After you have the full path `Cancel = True` will stop the SaveAs action so you can choose to save or not.

Edit: You determine if the user pressed `Save` button or `SaveAs` with `SaveAsUI`. If `Save` pressed then `SaveAsUI = False` if `SaveAs` then `SaveAsUI = True`

Edit 2: 
This is an example of how I would implement the above:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    'cancel all default actions by excel application
    Cancel = True

    'if save was selected instead of SaveAs
    If (SaveAsUI = False) Then
        Cancel = False

    'if SaveAs was selected
    ElseIf (SaveAsUI = True) Then

        SaveAsUI = False
        Dim intChoice As Integer
        Dim strPath As String

        'make the file dialog visible to the user
        intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show

        'determine what choice the user made
        If intChoice <> 0 Then
            'get the file path selected by the user
            strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)

            'get file extention
            fileExt = Right(strPath, Len(strPath) - InStr(strPath, ".") + 1)

            'if pdf is the chosen format
            If (InStr(strPath, "PDF") > 0) Then

                'actions with pdf format
                Call MsgBox(strPath, vbInformation, "Save Path")
            Else

                With ActiveWorkbook
                    'on error resume next in case of extention macro free prompt no is selected
                    'see example by removing on error resume next and saving extention ".xlsx"
                    On Error Resume Next
                    .SaveAs strPath
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End With

            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The SaveAs action is initiated by the user's calling the SaveAs dialog. Then your solution would present him with another SaveAs dialog. Please read the last sentence of my question. You are suggesting a way which I expressly wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Variatus, If you're trying to prevent the user being served two `SaveAs` `File Dialog` prompts, you simple need to turn `SaveAsUI = False` and the original `SaveAs action` is blocked. To prevent the `File Dialog` if the user only tries to `Save`, wrap it with `SaveAsUI = False` which is the default save event state for the UI. Trying to determine the output of something that didn't happen seems like the wrong option when you can control the process, as an example you stop needing `AfterSave` to revert the file, instead create a new file to save as PDF. If not .PDF simply save as intended.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have up-voted your response but can't accept your answer. Again, here is the sequence: the user clicks SaveAs and selects PDF (or not). I want to know what he selected. Undoing the SaveAs action won't put the dialog back in the box because it was already shown. The alternative is to give him a button with which to call SaveAs and then everything is easy.  I am resigned to do that now but it isn't what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Variatus, I added an example of how I would implement this, I think it covers most of what you would need. But any way best of luck ^^